# java heap space when space is actually available

Tags: java, jms, heap-memory, activemq-classic, amq

I'm trying to send a BytesMessage on AMQ (5.15.2) but I run in a heap space exception even if the memory is clearly available. Here is the

```
byte[] contcentBuilder = new Byte[1000*1000*1];
Array.fill(contentBuilder, (byte) 1);
BytesMessage message = session.createBytesMessage();
for(int i=0;i<150;i++){
    message.writeBytes(contentBuilder);
}
contentBuilder=null;
producer.send(message); //here it gets the heap space memory error
Runtime.getRunTime().freeMemory(); //this is in debug
```

In the bug the memory available is over 15Gb (I allocated 16Gb to this VM).

Any ideas are welcome, thank you.

EDIT: I'm basically dumb, the problem was on the AMQ side of things and increasing it's memory in the bin/win64/wrapper.conf did the job. thanks to all who answered.

New here I don't know how to close this answer!

Comment: Are you sure this even compiles? `byte[]` is not the same thing as `Byte[]`.

Comment: Besides, I made some accounts and the memory allocated by that array is about 0.0009 GB
"http://www.matisse.net/bitcalc/?input_amount=1000000&input_units=bytes&notation=legacy" which makes me think that the problem is not the ram allocated to the VM

Comment: @GianfrancescoAurecchia, it's 150 million bytes, actually. If I understand what `BytesMessage` does.

Comment: so i would say to use -Xmx when i jung the execution command, let me know how it goes

Comment: sorry I did not give importance to the cycle, in all cases occupies only 0.1396 GB

Comment: @M.Prokhorov it compiles I'm sure, it goes in heap space error if the value of the cycle is >104, unde that works just fine.

Comment: @GianfrancescoAurecchia I already set the -Xms and -Xmx to 16Gb

Comment: @Ayeyebraso, doesn't compile on my end, just as I thought. You must have either `byte[]` or `Byte[]`, assigning one to another will not work (and should not work for that matter).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov oh man, I have to write code on an offline pc so I couldn't copy/paste the code and had to type it by hand and made a typo... it's byte[] contentBuilder=new byte[1000*1000*1];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still me, the problem was on the AMQ side of things and increasing it's memory in the bin/win64/wrapper.conf did the job. thanks to all who answered.